# Jest cannot read property of undefined object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs

Inside React Native, I create a `theme.js` file where I have some functions that get my colors based on the design system in the company.

```
// theme.js

const PRIMARY_COLORS = {
  900: '#000000',
  800: '#003030',
  700: '#004040',
  600: '#006060',
  500: '#00A090',
  400: '#00C0A0',
  300: '#00E0D0',
  200: '#C0FFF0',
  100: '#E0FFF0',
};

export function _primaryColor(code) {
  return PRIMARY_COLORS[code];
}
```

When running jest with React's default test it throws an error saying that `PRIMARY_COLORS` is undefined.

```
// App-test.tsx

import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.useFakeTimers();

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```

If the object is inside the function the test will run correctly, but that means that the object will be instantiated every time the function runs.

Is there a way I can go around this thing?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are using theme.js in your App component,so in your App's test file mock theme.js file,and that should fix the error.

Comment: I mocked them inside App-text.tsx and it didn't work

Comment: How are you mocking it?can you show your test file code

Comment: Test file was described in the question. It's `App-test.tsx`

Comment: no i am saying how have you mocked theme.js file in your App-test.tsx file

Comment: I don't know how to mock it properly, because I don't know what I need to do.
i tried `jest.mock('../src/utils/theme.ts')` and it was still broken

Comment: Should I mock the entire module? Or just the functions?

Comment: try mocking it like this:`const mockGetprimaryColor = jest.fn();
jest.mock("provide absolute path here", () => ({
  _primaryColor: (...args: any) => mockGetprimaryColor
}));`

Answer (score 1):

As @Sakshi suggested, I mocked the functions in the test file as follows

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../App';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

jest.useFakeTimers();

jest.mock('../theme.ts', () => {
  const PRIMARY_COLORS = {
    900: '#000000',
    800: '#003030',
    700: '#004040',
    600: '#006060',
    500: '#00A090',
    400: '#00C0A0',
    300: '#00E0D0',
    200: '#C0FFF0',
    100: '#E0FFF0',
  };

  return {
    _primaryColor: (code) => PRIMARY_COLORS[code],
  };
});

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  renderer.create(<App />);
});
```